# Real world context for projectile motion problem given start speed and angle and end angle

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, projectile, education

For my Newtonian mechanics class I want to create a projectile motion problem where initial and final angle are given as well as the initial speed of the projectile. Then the students should  calculate the $x$ and $y$ coordinates of the target (or equivalently of the launch position). Now I am looking for a good context from real world or science or engineering where this variant of the projectile problem naturally arises. Air drag should be negligible in the context. Neither the start nor the end position should be horizontal.

Comment: Let's say we want to send a parcel from Paris to New York via cannonball. Using real coordinates on a sphere and real Newtonian gravity, what is the angle and speed should we throw the cannonball from Paris for it to exactly land in New York?

Comment: @James: Thanks, but that's not a "real world" example, air resistance is not negligible in this case and last but not least it doesn't respect the constraints of my question (in my question the angles are given as well as the initial speed).

Comment: Sorry I tried some more but can't think of any, the "end angle known" is bugging me somehow, how is the end angle known beforehand and what problem could this be...

Comment: Why was this question closed? What's not clear about the question?